# Django progress bar for registration

Tags: python, django

Guys I am currently doing registration for courses and each course has 12 place

here the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQOAa.png)

when users register for any course it should be counted 
my `views.py` file

```
def register_course(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserRegisterForCourse(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        select_course = form.cleaned_data.get('select_course')
        messages.success(request, f'You have been successfully registered for {select_course}')
        return redirect('blog-home')
else:
    form = UserRegisterForCourse()
    return render(request, 'blog/register_course.html', {'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
class RegisterForCourse(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
COURSE_CHOICES = (
    ('Python', 'Python'),
    ('Java', 'Java'),
    ('JavaScript', 'JavaScript'),
    ('C#', 'C#'),
    ('C++', 'C++'),
    ('Web', 'Web'),
)
select_course = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=COURSE_CHOICES)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)

def __str__(self):
    return self.select_course
```

and the template file

```
<div class="content-section">
        <h3>Register for courses</h3>
          <p class='text-muted'>Very few places left</p>
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Python
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="2"><div></div></div> <span>2</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Java
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="12"><div></div></div> <span>5</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">JavaScript
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="7"><div></div></div> <span>7</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">C#
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="8"><div></div></div> <span>8</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">C++
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="8"><div></div></div> <span>8</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Web
                <div class="float-right">
                    <div class="my-progress" data-count="8"><div></div></div> <span>8</span>/12
                </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
```

I cannot do this proccess can you help me please? Now i am using sqlite database I have not added database yet. Course field is a select option according to the selection of user, progress bar should be progressed properly.

> Thank you beforehand! Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think this is issue for frontend stack. Just add a progress status and add +1 when  the progress is done

Comment: seuling yes i did front end part but back end part it should be counted. how can i add a code for this issue

Comment: Well.. there's many way to do it. First it's bit helpful for you to upload your front part. If you want to async approach, you don't need your backend part. If not, you can use ajax to change status or just change status in every form send.

Comment: thanks a vlot for your advice idea about this has not been existed fully but i understood a bit how to do it anyway I will try. Thanks)